# android.support.customtabs error after updating to android studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-design-library

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [com.android.support:customtabs:23.2.1] 2/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/customtabs/23.2.1/AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.customtabs" to force usage

why this coming ?

this coming after updating to andorid studio 2.0

Comment: what is your minSdk ? if it is 14 change it to 16 and try. also update buildtool version to 2.0.0

Comment: i want it to supoort till 14

Answer (score 0):

add `<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.customtabs"/>` to your manifest,
And also  include 
`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in root of your manifest file 
like

[image]

Comment: after updating to new lib design all custom tab view broken

Comment: If you want to support SDK 14, then you need to write above line in your manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you already have that tag tool:overrideLibrary="example library" and you need to use that for more than one, just separe with "," as this example:

`<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.example.lib1, com.example.lib2"/>`